# Algorithm for coloring boxes on a sudoku board

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I'm currently writing a graphical sudoku solver program in `Java` using Swing/Awt. So I decided I wanted to shade the boxes (marked with thicker lines) on the board the way these are (with 3x3 and 2x3 boxes):
[image]
<sub>(source: [zitowolf.net](http://zitowolf.net/sudoku/images/bd6x6.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [zitowolf.net](http://zitowolf.net/sudoku/images/bd8x8.png))</sub>

A 6x6 board and a 8x8 board

A board in the program is basically represented as an `int[dimension][dimension]` array and the the program accepts boards with dimensions from 4x4 -> 16x16.

**The problem is to make sure no boxes next to each other in a row or column has the same shading. The GUI shading process itself is not the problem, but finding out whether a square should be shaded as part of a shaded box.**

I've tried for hours to implement a simple algorithm for this problem going through the array with a double for-loop, but I haven't gotten any reasonable pattern yet and I'm out of ideas. My algorithm so far is based on the assumption that every other box should be colored from top left to right bottom. This doesn't work for the 6x6 variant because there you have the sequence: colored box->white box->white box.

Could anyone here suggest an algorithm or another approach? I'll provide more info if needed. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool should_shade(x,y,size_x,size_y) 
//sizes are size of small box and position x,y count from 0
{
     return ( (x/size_x + y/size_y ) % 2) == 0; //division is integer division

}
```

Comment: How would i rewrite this return statement in `Java`? The compiler yields: `... operator ! cannot be applied to int ...`.

Comment: This worked great! Only, I changed the parts to `x/size_y` and `y/size_x` to make it work with `should_shade(i,j,boxWidth,boxHeight)` where `boxWidth` is the number of columns and `boxHeight` number of rows in a box. I have no clue why this arithmetic works, but it's awesome!

Comment: @hesse It works because if you increase `x / size_x` (i.e. the x-index of the box this square is in) by one, it changes color; if you increase `y / size_y` by one, it also changes color. That will definitely satisfy your requirement that no two adjacent boxes have the same color.